# Need help improving my background image in CSS

Tags: html, css

In this Index page: http://www.apxhotels.com there are 8 diamonds and hotel names. Instead of text I want  element on the image as well as the text. What do I have to change in my CSS to achieve this?

Below is the CSS I am currently using:

```
.content_menu{ 
    width:1210px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:-87px
    height:96px;
    z-index:10
}
.content_menu ul li{ 
    margin-right:20px; 
    background:url(../images/menu_down.png); 
    width:113px; 
    height:96px; 
    display:inline-block; 
    text-align:center;
}
.content_menu ul li a:hover{
    color:#939598;
}
.content_menu ul li a{
    font-family: Cambria; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-size:14px; 
    text-align:center;
    position:relative; 
    top:46px;
}
.content_menu ul li:last-child{
    margin-right:0px;
}
.content_menu ul{
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you want to achieve, you have 8 diamonds with text and image inside. Please be more specific

Comment: Write now hyperlink is on text. I want hyperlink on diamond as well as text.

Comment: Even checking the site he mentioned and triple-checking his question I have **no clue** as of what the OP asks for.

Comment: Okay, got it now. Check my answer below and apply the styles.

Comment: Not a duplicate since the OP does not want or do this. It's just a wrong answer he received proposing this.

Comment: I like how it says 'possible duplicate' since the answers to both OP are related, rather than 'actual duplicate'

Answer (score 1):

## Quickfix

Add the following css declarations to your stylesheet's definitions:

```
.content_menu ul li a {
    ... 
    line-height: 89px; /* height of parent <li> minus padding-top of this link */
    display: block;
    padding-top: 7px; /* instead of 46px as currently defined in your css */
}
```

and remove those two from the same ruleset:

```
position: relative;
top: 46px;
```

This will do two things: First setting `display: block;` makes sure your link grab the full with of the surrounding `<li>`, expanding the horizontally clickable area. Then you make the link just as high as the list item by setting the lineheight accordingly. Done!